# Fill column with last 30 dates in descending order

Tags: google-sheets

How to (in Google Sheets) create column with last 30/60/... dates in descending order, starting from today? I have tried to start with something like `TODAY()-30` and autofill the rest of cells but it doesn't work.

Eg:

```
|2018-10-01|
|2018-09-30|
|2018-09-29|
|...       |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first cell, say `A1`, enter `=TODAY()`. Then in `A2`, enter `=A1-1`. Autofill starting from `A2`.